# ¿Por qué este integer de repente cambia de valor?

Tags: c

Estoy preparando una pequeña shell en C. Tengo preparado un puntero con los procedimientos en segundo plano, llamado jobs. El caso es que el pid del segundo y tercer proceso cambian sin motivo aparente. Teniendo el siguiente código:

```
    if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid);
    if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid);
    if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid);
```

En la primera ejecución se devuelve un 2, que es lo que debería devolver, pero en la segunda, sin haber cambiado absolutamente nada de repente se convierte en un 544437093, y en la tercera en un 544433440.

No tengo ni idea de porque esto pasa. La aplicación está en una fase muy temprana de desarrollo, así que os pasaré todo el código. Creo que puedo haber hecho mal algo relacionado con la memoria.

parser.h

```
typedef struct {
    char * filename;
    int argc;
    char ** argv;
} tcommand;

typedef struct {
    int ncommands;
    tcommand * commands;
    char * redirect_input;
    char * redirect_output;
    char * redirect_error;
    int background;
}   tline;

typedef struct {
    int argc;
    char **argv;
    int pid;
} proccess;

typedef struct {
    proccess* procs;
    int size;
} procesos;

extern tline * tokenize(char *str);
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "parser.h"
#include <string.h>
int size_t2int(size_t val) {
    return (int)((ssize_t)val);
}

int
main(void) {
    char buf[1024];
    tline * line;
    int i,j,k,esbackground,argact;
    esbackground = 0;
    procesos jobs;
    jobs.size = 0;
    argact=0;
    jobs.procs = (proccess*) malloc(sizeof(proccess));
    printf("==> ");
    while (fgets(buf, 1024, stdin)) {
        printf ("el jobs size es %d\n",jobs.size);
        line = tokenize(buf);

        if (line==NULL) {
            continue;
        }
        if (line->redirect_input != NULL) {
            printf("redirección de entrada: %s\n", line->redirect_input);
        }
        if (line->redirect_output != NULL) {
            printf("redirección de salida: %s\n", line->redirect_output);
        }
        if (line->redirect_error != NULL) {
            printf("redirección de error: %s\n", line->redirect_error);
        }
        if (line->background) {
            printf("comando a ejecutarse en background\n");
            esbackground = 1;
            jobs.procs[jobs.size].pid=1+jobs.size;
            if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid); //aquí el pid se imprime bien
            if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid); //a partir de aquí el process ID se ve alterado.
            if (jobs.size>0) printf("The process ID 2 is %d\n",jobs.procs[1].pid);
        } 


        for (i=0; i<line->ncommands; i++) {
            printf("orden %d (%s):\n", i, line->commands[i].filename);
            jobs.procs[jobs.size].argc = line->commands[i].argc;

            argact+=line->commands[i].argc;
        }
        jobs.procs[jobs.size].argc = argact;
        if (esbackground) jobs.size+=1;
        esbackground = 0;
        argact = 0;
        for (i=0; i<jobs.size; i++){
        printf("[ %d ] ",jobs.procs[i].pid);
        printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
        printf("==> ");

    }
    return 0;
}
```

También estoy utilizando una librería libparser.a para la función tokenize.

He insertado 11 PID, escribiendo manualmente comandos en segundo plano al abrir la aplicación, para comprobar como quedarían. Solo el segundo y tercero dan problemas:

```
==> g &
el jobs size es 10
comando a ejecutarse en background
The process ID 2 is 1785012321
The process ID 2 is 544437093
The process ID 2 is 544437093
orden 0 ((null)):
[ 1 ] 
[ 1970153512 ] 
[ 681070 ] 
[ 4 ] 
[ 5 ] 
[ 6 ] 
[ 7 ] 
[ 8 ] 
[ 9 ] 
[ 10 ] 
[ 11 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jobs.procs = (proccess*) malloc(sizeof(proccess));
```

Estás reservando espacio para únicamente un elemento, luego esta instrucción:

```
jobs.procs[1].pid
```

Está accediendo a un elemento que no pertenece al elemento anterior. Como estás teniendo la *suerte* de que esa memoria pertenece a tu programa el Sistema Operativo no mata tu proceso. Lo que sucede es que esa memoria está siendo utilizada (o puede usarse ya que no la tienes reservada para ese arreglo) para otras operaciones y por eso se sobreescribe su valor.

Recuerda que en C los índices empiezan en 0, luego el primer elemento es:

```
jobs.procs[0].pid
```

O también

```
jobs.procs->pid
```